# SQLite data not getting deleted in my RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to delete data from SQLite database but it's not working.

See SQlite database **`DELETE`** Query :

```
public void deleteCompany(long company_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete(COMPANY, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(company_id) });
}
```

Where to i delete a data **`CompaniesFragment.java`** :

```
rvCompanies_view.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), rvCompanies_view, new AddAffiliatedCompanyActivity.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLongClick(final View child, final int childPosition) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");  
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this Company?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                myDb.deleteCompany(childList.get(childPosition).getId());
                childList.remove(childPosition);
                adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Company Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View child, int childPosition) {
    }
}));
```

Below code is available on RecyclerView but i'll to define separate for batter understanding :

```
myDb.deleteCompany(childList.get(childPosition).getId());
childList.remove(childPosition);
adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Company Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**UPDATE**

I'll change my code see below :

```
Log.e("TAG", "Size Of Array :" + childList.size());
                        Log.e("TAG", "Id" + childList.get(childPosition).getId());
    myDb.deleteCompany(childList.get(childPosition).getId());
                        childList.remove(childPosition);
                        adapterRecycler.notifyItemRemoved(childPosition);
                        //adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + childList);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Company Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**AND IT'S GIVE ME THE ERROR :** **`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2`**

**It's just a show a Toast message only nothing to delete a data or any thing**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved :

**The PROBLEM IS DATA POSITION**

1st Problem is below line :

```
 List<Company> childList = new ArrayList<Company>();
```

Above line create a problem of with my array list becoze i'll use this adapter variable becoz of that i can't get any array size

So i print the **`LOG`** and see Array Size :

```
Log.e("TAG", "Size Of Array :" + childList.size() + "Position :" + childList);
```

2nd i Print the **`LOG`** Of my data ID :

```
Log.e("TAG", "Id" + childList.get(childPosition).getId());
```

then i understand data was show in DESC order and i'll change my above line Like My below line :

```
Log.e("TAG", "Id" + childList.get(childPosition - 1 ).getId());
```

Then After i delete My Record using below line :

```
myDb.deleteCompany(childList.get(childPosition).getId());
```

Above line delete a record but if suppose in array 1 record then it's Generate the error.

Then i'll change the code:

```
myDb.deleteCompany(childList.get(childPosition - 1 ).getId());
```

**AND MY PROBLEM WAS SOLVED**

See Full code of My Solution :

```
Log.e("TAG", "Size Of Array :" + childList.size() + "Position :" + childList);
Log.e("TAG", "Id" + childList.get(childPosition - 1 ).getId());
myDb.deleteCompany(childList.get(childPosition - 1 ).getId());
rvCompanies_view.removeViewAt(childPosition);
Log.e("TAG", "Size Of Array :" + childList.size() + "Position :" + childList);
adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Company Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
adapterRecycler.notifyItemRemoved(childPosition)
adapterRecycler.notifyItemRangeChanged(childPosition, getItemCount());
```

instead of

```
adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: what is **`getItemCount()`**?

Comment: `adapterRecycler.getItemCount()`

Comment: ya this is okay but whenever i used this line **`adapterRecycler.notifyItemRangeChanged(childPosition, getItemCount());`** then it's give the error

Comment: What was the error? Then you can just remove it.. It is just for smoother item remove.. you can just use `adapterRecycler.notifyItemRemoved()` only

Comment: this line **`adapterRecycler.notifyItemRemoved()`** said pass the parameter in this bracket. so which parameter pass in bracket

Comment: oh im sorry i forgot to pass the position. check edit

Comment: then what about this line **`childList.remove(childPosition);`** i already use in my code. **so can i remove this ?**

Comment: no. that removes the item in the list. you only need to change `notifyDataSetChanged` with `notifyItemRemoved`

Comment: it's give me the error like **`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2`**

Comment: error log just show a error which i show in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169412/discussion-between-android-k-doe-and-mohammad-ali).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help brother @Android_K.Doe

Answer (score 0):

make interface into recycler view adapter for click handle like below code ..

```
 onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

public void setOnItemClickListner(RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

public interface onItemClickListner {
    void onClick(String str);//pass your object types.
}


  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String data = mStringList.get(position); // if you pass object of class then create that class object.

    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListner.onClick(data);
        }
    });
```

then after in activity after bind adapter into recycler view put below code  ..

```
        recyclerViewAdpater.setOnItemClickListner(new RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(String str) {
            // here you show your alert dialog.
            // below code remove item from list
            stringsList.remove(stringsList.indexOf(str));
            recyclerViewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i think your error indexoutofbound when remove item from list there for used stringsList.remove(stringsList.indexOf(str));

Comment: ya but you can see in my answer i can remove this line